# How can I select a column name that contains non ascii characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the values from a column name with non-ascii characters but It cant be possible.

The column name is "DescripÃ³n" and I want to remove the "Ã³" and transform it in `&Atilde; &#179;`.

How can I make the select?

Comment: Create another table with the desired column names and `insert into that_other_table select * from funny_names_table` then delete the original and rename new to old.

Answer (score 2):

You can use special characters if you use delimited identifiers:

```
mysql> create table mytable ( `DescripÃ³n` text );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable (`DescripÃ³n`) values ('hello world');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select `DescripÃ³n` from mytable;
+--------------+
| DescripÃ³n   |
+--------------+
| hello world  |
+--------------+
```

If you want to change the column name to only ASCII characters so you can use it subsequently without delimiting it:

```
mysql> alter table mytable change column `DescripÃ³n` Description text;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select Description from mytable;
+-------------+
| Description |
+-------------+
| hello world |
+-------------+
```

But you cannot use HTML entities like `&Atilde;&#179;` in MySQL queries, sorry.